# How do I configure omniauth use memcached as a backing store with google in classic sinatra app?

Tags: oauth, sinatra, omniauth

I am attempting to debug an issue where doing oauth with Google when there are multiple app servers behind an EC2 ELB is failing. I believe the issue is related to the fact that the oauth backing store is not being shared. The solution we had in place worked fine for 2+ years, then suddenly started to fail 2 days ago and I don't know if it is a configuration issue on my end or google changed something.

I believe to fix things I must use a shared store such as memcached.

Here is my attempt to do so in my classic style sinatra app:

```
Sinatra::Application.use ::OmniAuth::Strategies::OpenID do
  OpenID::Store::Memcache.new(Memcached.new('my_memcached_machine'))
end
```

Unfortunately this still has not resolved the issue. As far as I can tell, OmniAuth is never doing any get or set requests to memcached.

Is this the correct way to get omniauth to use memcached while attempting to authenticate with google in a classic-style sinatra app?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach I have discovered that works, but I'm sure there is a better way...

```
module Rack
  class OpenID
    def initialize(app, store = nil)
      @app = app
      @store = ::OpenID::Store::Memcache.new(OpenIDMemcachedManager.new('...'))
    end
  end
end
```